# Not able to retrieve data from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am saving data to firebase successfully

```
    const productsRef = db.collection("store").doc(userID).collection("products");

    productsRef
      .doc(productID)
      .set({
        userID: userID,
        productCatagory: productCatagory.value,
        productCode: productID,
        productName: productName.value,
        price: price.value,
        description: description.value,
        time: time,
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
```

But when i try to retrieve it firestore sends "No such document". Trying to get the array of objects.

```
db.collection("store")
      .doc(userID)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data());
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
```

Here is the db

[image]

Edit: I found out that in order to access all documents you have to do it this way.

```
db.collection("store")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots

          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

It goes into the then block but then querySnapshot.forEach doesnt run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i found the solution.

```
db.collection(`store/${userID}/products`)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      });
```